# How to escape backslash and double quote in Ansible (script module)

Tags: ansible

I'm very new to Ansible (2.x) and I am having trouble using the script module and passing parameters with double quotes and backslashes.

Assuming we have a set variable `{{foo}}` which contains a string "foo", I have a task like this:

```
set_fact:
   arg: \(-name "{{foo}}" \)
name: call shell module
script: path/somescript.sh "{{arg}}"
```

My script needs the following structure of the argument in order to work:

```
\(-name "foo" \)
```

I tried several things such as:

```
arg: \(-name \""{{foo}}"\" \)           result: \\(-name \"foo\" \\)

arg: '\(-name \""{{foo}}"\" \)'         result: \\(-name \"foo\" \\)

arg: \\(-name \""{{foo}}"\" \\)           result: \\(-name \"foo\" \\)
```

Is it possible to escape backslashes and double quotes in Ansible?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Don't be confused by the fact that ansible-playbook prints debug messages in JSON encoded form, so some characters are escaped.

```
set_fact:
  arg: \(-name "{{foo}}" \)
```

You have correct syntax. This will set `arg` to `\(-name "bar" \)` if `foo`'s value is `bar`.
But the debug message in this case will look like this:

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "arg": "\\(-name \"bar\" \\)"
}
```

Note that special characters for JSON (`"` and `\`) are escaped.

But there may be some issues with passing this as parameter.
If you call your script like this

```
script: path/somescript.sh "{{arg}}"
```

Parameter string will look like this `"\(-name "bar" \)"` which is actually 3 concatenated strings in bash: `\(-name` +`bar`+ `\)`, so you will lose double quotes around the *bar*.

If you want to preserve those double quotes, use:

```
script: path/somescript.sh '{{arg}}'
```

Comment: The single quotes were the key to solution. And you were right, the characters will be eventually escaped when passing to the script. I can't upvote as I've got too less reputation but my thanks are yours :-)

Comment: The single quotes did the job. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. I am passing a list of path with with_items. When I use win_shell and "{{item}}" backslashes are not added correctly. How can we use a loop variable in win_shell?

Answer (score 2):

You're very close. I think you want to set a variable, not a fact, and I would suggest you use the `shell` module instead of the `script` module. `shell` is more forgiving when it comes to escaping and quoting complex shell commands.

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    foo: test.yml
    arg: \( -name "{{ foo }}" \)
  tasks:
    - debug: var=arg
    - shell: find . {{ arg }}
      register: find
    - debug: var=find.stdout_lines
```

And the output:

```
$ ansible-playbook test.yml 

PLAY [localhost] ***************************************************************

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "arg": "\\( -name \"test.yml\" \\)"
}

TASK [command] *****************************************************************
changed: [localhost]

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "find.stdout_lines": [
        "./test.yml"
    ]
}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=3    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

Comment: I'm using the shell script now. Combined with the answer of Konstatin Suvorov (single quotation when passing to script as arg), this helped me out. Thank you very much!