# ansible duplicates slashes in windows file path

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

Trying to test simple ansible script I defined a variable.

```
variable: C:\Log\1.txt
```

Next I simply try to echo this variable.

```
-name: echo
  debug: msg="{{ variable }}"
```

Got:

```
 "msg": "C:\\Log\\1.txt"
```

Expected output:

```
"msg": "C:\Log\1.txt"
```

How can I get one slash in path output?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't be confused by the fact that ansible-playbook prints debug messages in JSON encoded form, so some characters are escaped.
There's no duplicated slashes in the variable's value.

See my answer for different question for details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39587120/2795592