# How to escape double-quotes in ansible variable

Tags: ansible

I have an ansible playbook which accepts a variable, passing a variable with quotes in it(its needed), that variable will used to query against DB

Playbook

```
- name: Execute clear script
  script: scripts/clear-documents.sh {{ids}}
```

Command

```
ansible-playbook playbooks/maintenance.yml -i hosts -t clear -e ids=["foo", "bar"]
```

in this process script receives the input as [foo, bar] instead of ["foo", "bar"]

I tried escaping using backslash but that did not help

```
ansible-playbook playbooks/maintenance.yml -i hosts -t clear -e ids=[\"foo\", \"bar\"]
```

Adding double quotes in playbook, makes the input like "[foo,bar]" and not ["foo", "bar"]

```
script: scripts/clear-documents.sh "{{ids}}"
```

I searched a lot but did not get any proper solution, is there a way to handler this

Note:
ansible version - 2.2.3.0

Comment: Quoting hell ;-) `-e ids=\"\[\\\"foo\",\"bar\\\"]\"` or more readable `-e ids='["foo","bar"]'
`

Comment: .. get a little closer to paradise (but just a little) `-e 'ids="[\"foo\", \"bar\"]"'`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to escape backslash and double quote in Ansible (script module)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39580797/how-to-escape-backslash-and-double-quote-in-ansible-script-module)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The thing you are looking for is [quote](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.7/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#id8), in combination with @JGK's correct usage of `-e ids='["foo", "bar"]'` because you were not quoting them on the way *into* ansible, and then you were not quoting them on the way *out* of ansible in that `shell:` task

```
- shell: scripts/clear-documents.sh {{ ids | quote }}
```

Answer (score 0):

As is mentioned in [How to escape backslash and double quote in Ansible (script module)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39580797/how-to-escape-backslash-and-double-quote-in-ansible-script-module?rq=1) you need to surround the `{{ ids }}` with `' '` in your shell command.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ansible-playbook
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  become: false
  tasks:
  - name: Escape characters for fun and profit
    vars:
      string_list: '["one", "two"]'
    shell: "echo '{{ string_list }}'"
    register: output1

  - name: Print it out
    debug:
      msg: "{{ output1 }}"

  - name: Don't escape characters
    vars:
      string_list: '["one", "two"]'
    shell: "echo {{ string_list }}"
    register: output2

  - name: Print it out
    debug:
      msg: "{{ output2 }}"


PLAY [localhost] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Escape characters for fun and profit] *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [localhost]

TASK [Print it out] *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": {
        "changed": true,
        "cmd": "echo '[\"one\", \"two\"]'",
        "delta": "0:00:00.003400",
        "end": "2019-05-07 12:02:32.897856",
        "failed": false,
        "rc": 0,
        "start": "2019-05-07 12:02:32.894456",
        "stderr": "",
        "stderr_lines": [],
        "stdout": "[\"one\", \"two\"]",
        "stdout_lines": [
            "[\"one\", \"two\"]"
        ]
    }
}

TASK [Don't escape characters] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [localhost]

TASK [Print it out] *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": {
        "changed": true,
        "cmd": "echo [\"one\", \"two\"]",
        "delta": "0:00:00.002990",
        "end": "2019-05-07 12:02:33.192049",
        "failed": false,
        "rc": 0,
        "start": "2019-05-07 12:02:33.189059",
        "stderr": "",
        "stderr_lines": [],
        "stdout": "[one, two]",
        "stdout_lines": [
            "[one, two]"
        ]
    }
}

PLAY RECAP ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=4    changed=2    unreachable=0    failed=0
```